# Meaning of "suffrage by someone"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions

In the sentence

> Universal suffrage **by** the whole people of
>   representatives and rulers of the state --  this is the last
>   word of the Marxists as well as of the democratic school.

can the word 'by' be replaced with 'for' with no change in meaning? If suffrage is a kind of right, shouldn't it be **for** people?

Comment: whole people of representatives is meaningless...universal suffrage would not normally be followed by "by"

Comment: Suffrage is a kind of "action" (that can be done ***by*** specified agents) here, not a kind of "right".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, *suffrage* is not used as "the right to vote", but in one of its alternative meanings: "the exercise of one's right to vote".  (See the '3 also' definition at [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suffrage).)  The use of 'by' is actually key to indicating this meaning.  The sentence could be rephrased as "100% voter turnout when electing representatives and rulers is the ultimate goal of both Marxists and the democratic school."

If you replaced *by* with *for*, you would be indicating *suffrage* as "the right to vote", but then the 'of' clause makes no sense: how do representatives and rulers relate to everyone having the right to vote?